# i want to present an int as hh:mm:ss format

Tags: sql

i have a this line

```
CASE WHEN sum(srv_grp_answd_cnt)=0 THEN NULL ELSE (cast(SUM(srv_grp_answd_dur) as int) / cast(sum(srv_grp_answd_cnt)as int)) END AS avg_grp_answd_dur
```

it returns me seconds as int

i want to present it as hh:mm:ss format

Can anyone help ?

Comment: As the [tag:sql] tag suggests, you ought to add a tag for your specific RDBMS product. This is either going to involve a timespan data type, if your database has such a thing, or string formatting. Either one will be product specific.

Comment: 60 seconds is one minute and 60 minutes 's 1 hour (or 3600 seconds = 1 hour). 1 day is 86400 seconds. What else do you need? Every database I know have some sort of conversion functions. Even if they didn't, it is simple math.
And also, any database I know of have a AVG() - average aggregate function.

Comment: ANSI SQL: `cast(seconds as interval hour to second)`.